# Duplicate editing dialog should work the same as the close vote dialog

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, close-dialog

I'm a vivid user of the [new duplicate target editing feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824) for gold badge holders. However, one thing that greatly annoys me is that the dialog window that pops up when adding a second question does not work the same as the dialog to cast duplicate close votes. Specifically, I **cannot submit** it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after having pasted an URI to the input field, and instead have to use the mouse to click the "*Add Original*" button.

Comment: Oops. I must have overlooked that in the suggestions.

Comment: I find it ironic that this question on duplicates was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @SandPiper At least I didn't have to edit the duplicate target…